# Docker's "executable file not found in $PATH: unknown" trying to run "cd"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've written the following `Dockerfile` which is supposed to run an arbitrary command (by providing one through arguments of `docker run`):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt -y update && apt-get -y update 
RUN apt install -y python3 git

CMD bash
```

But when I'm trying to pass the command, e.g. `cd workspace` I get the following:

```
C:\Users\user>docker run -it cloudbuildtoolset:latest cd workspace
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please don't suggest me to restart my machine/docker/whatever

Comment: Strictly speaking, cd is not a command. It's a builtin, and it can't be directly invoked. Consider using the [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) Dockerfile directive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cd` is a [special built-in utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), in the language of the POSIX shell specification.  It's something that changes the behavior of the running shell and not a standalone program.  The error message means what it says: there is no `/bin/cd` or similar executable you can run.

Remember that a Docker container runs a single process, then exits, losing whatever state it has.  It might not make sense for that single command to just change the container's working directory.

If you want to run a process inside a container but in a different working directory, you can use the [`docker run -w`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-working-directory--w) option

```sh
docker run -it \
  -w /workspace \
  cloudbuildtoolset:latest \
  the command you want to run
```

or, equivalently, add a `WORKDIR` directive to your Dockerfile.

You can also launch a shell wrapper as the main container process.  This would be able to use built-in commands like `cd`, but it's more complex to use and can introduce quoting issues.

```sh
docker run -it cloudbuildtoolset:latest \
  /bin/sh -c 'cd /workspace && the command you want to run'
```